# How to prevent SQL injection in Android?

Tags: java, android, sql-injection

Security alert

Your app contains a SQL Injection Vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article for details.

Vulnerable classes:

provider/FormsProvider;->query

Affects APK version 6.

```
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
            String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        qb.setTables(FORMS_TABLE_NAME);

        switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case FORMS:
                qb.setProjectionMap(sFormsProjectionMap);
                break;

            case FORM_ID:
                qb.setProjectionMap(sFormsProjectionMap);
                qb.appendWhere(FormsColumns._ID + "=" + uri.getPathSegments().get(1));
                break;

            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        // Get the database and run the query
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        // Tell the cursor what uri to watch, so it knows when its source data changes
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }
```

Please help me. How I can prevent SQL-injection security alert from google play console.

Comment: Do you even know what a SQL Injection Vulnerability is?

Comment: `Please fix the issue before: 09/16/2018` It's too late, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please read more about SQL injection [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You should NEVER put raw (unsanitized) user input into a SQL query.
I suggest using libraries that handle this things and prevent possible SQL injections. I personally use [Room](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room), but take a look also at [Requery](https://github.com/requery/requery/)